# Descriptor com meta classe vs tradicional

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptors, metaclass

Andei assistindo os vídeos ([exemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ylfv3_5KqKs)) de Luciano Ramalho sobre *descriptors* com *metaclasse*.

Queria saber qual a vantagem desse modelo em relação à implementação mais tradicional de *descriptors* como [esse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example) exemplo na documentação:

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> m.y
5
```

---

Fiz um [teste](https://paste.ofcode.org/3bf7BnFPDsBwLfCyqi5EWwQ) e para mim pareceu funcionar igual. Notei também que no exemplo da documentação os métodos **getattr** e **setattr** não são usados como no [exemplo](https://speakerdeck.com/ramalho/a-visao-radical-na-pratica?slide=51) do Luciano:

```
class Quantidade(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.set_nome(self.__class__.__name__, id(self))

    def set_nome(self, prefix, key):
        self.nome_alvo = '%s_%s' % (prefix, key)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.nome_alvo)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value > 0:
            setattr(instance, self.nome_alvo, value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('valor deve ser > 0')


class ModeloMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, nome, bases, dic):
        super(ModeloMeta, cls).__init__(nome, bases, dic)
        for chave, attr in dic.items():
            if hasattr(atr, 'set_nome'):
                attr.set_nome('__' + nome, chave)

class Modelo(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModeloMeta


class ItemPedido(Modelo):
    peso = Quantidade()
    preco = Quantidade()

    def __init__(self, descricao, peso, preco):
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.peso = peso
        self.preco = preco
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade eu estava completamente desatualizado com relação aos novos recursos do python3.6+.
Python3.6 introduziu o protocolo descritor `object.__set_name__(self, owner, name)` chamado no momento em que a classe é criada.
Sendo assim, penso não ser mais necessário usar *metaclasse* para trabalhar com *Descriptors* a partir do Python3.6+. Segue a [publicação](https://dev.to/dawranliou/writing-descriptors-in-python-36) que usei li sobre o tema, ela até faz comparações entra a versão nova e o modo legado.

Comment: sim- isso mesmo - o `__set_name__` reduz o uso mais óbvio para as metaclasses, e sua existência torna o uso das mesmas opcionais na maioria dos casos.